# A quick question on data returned by jquery.ajax() call (EDITED)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**EDIT:** The original problem was due a stupid syntax mistake somewhere else, whicj I fixed. I have a new problem though, as described below

I have the following jquery.ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: servicesUrl + "/" + ID + "/tasks",
    dataType: "xml",
    success : createTaskListTable
});
```

The `createTaskListTable` function is defined as

```
function createTaskListTable(taskListXml) {
    $(taskListXml).find("Task").each(function(){  
        alert("Found task")     
    }); // each task
}
```

<del>Problem is: this doesn't work, I get an error saying `taskListXml` is not defined. JQuery documentation states that the success functions gets passed three arguments, the first of which is the data.</del>

How can I pass the data returned by `.ajax()` to my function with a variable name of my own choosing.

My problem now is that I'm getting the XML from a previous ajax call! How is this even possible? That previous function is defined as `function convertServiceXmlDataToTable(xml)`, so they don't use the same variable name.

Utterly confused. Is this some caching issue? If so, how can I clear the browser cache to get rid of the earlier XML?

Thanks!

Comment: Check the AJAX response in Firebug and make sure that it's valid XML.

Comment: If the data you get is valid, this should work.

Comment: if `taskListXml` was undefined, you wouldn't get any error: the function would just return without doing anything. What error exactly are you getting?

Comment: Just a thought, but what version of jQuery are you using, and have you seen anything in the bug tracking system about this? For each jQuery version, there's a comment system under each method description which people sometimes use to report bugs. Probably won't help you, but worth a shot...

Comment: you might try disabling caching (at least while you are developing) just to make sure the browser isn't caching an empty response.  just add "cache: false" to your options array.

Comment: @Ender, I think what you say may explain my new problem. How do I turn it off, where's this options array you mention. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment.  If you're using IE, GET AJAX requests are cached.  jQuery can solve this for you by adding a random querystring variable to the request.  Simply change your AJAX call to this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: servicesUrl + "/" + ID + "/tasks",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "xml",
    success : createTaskListTable
});
```

That will add the random querystring automatically, thus preventing the browser from caching the request.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your callback inline like this:

```
success: function createTaskListTable(data, textStatus, xhr) {
  console.dir(data, textStatus, xhr);
}
```

If data is indeed being returned as null, you might get some insight from the other fields, especially xhr.

Note that error callbacks get called with (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown).